# Image transform that only crops if image is larger than set dimensions

Tags: image-transforms, image

At the moment I have an image 300px wide, my transform is set to a width of 600px so it upscales it.

I would like it to only transform if the image is over 600px.

Is this possible or should I use some other image manipulation thing like phpthumb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this in twig with a conditional that checks if the width of the image is larger than your target transforms width. Try something like this:

```
{% if image.getWidth()>600 %}
  <img src="{{ image.getUrl({ width: 600 }) }}">
{% else %}
  <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
{% endif %}
```